# Android. How to create same context menu to use in all activities?

Tags: android, contextmenu

All activities has similar "**settings**" button. `OnClick`, I want to show context menu. All clicks are handled by separate method:

```
case Tags.TAG_SETTINGS://if settings button clicked
    a.registerForContextMenu(v);//a is activity
    a.openContextMenu(v);//v is view(settings button imageview)
    break;
```

I have tested this whether it is working or not. Tested in MainActivity

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Yeah", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

This is showing toast with message "Yeah".

My question is how to create universal context menu which will be used in all activities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a subclass of Activity and then make all your activities be a class of that. Then you could implement your common context menu in that class. e.g.

```
public class BaseActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
       //common logic for menu
    }
}
```

Then you would create your activity that would extend the base activity instead of activity.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a base activity and implement it there. All other activities can extend your base activity, if they need the context menu.